# Unable to get system thread id from python thread id in python 2.7

Tags: python, ubuntu

Python 2.6 used to have undocumented function called `tmap`. This function is not there in python 2.7.

This `tmap` function was there in threading package. I tried to search for any function in 2.7 that can provide similar functionality without luck.

I tried to port the tmap from python 2.6.7 to 2.7. It is something like:

def tmap():

```
ret = {}
_active_limbo_lock.acquire()
for k, val in _active.items():
    ret[k] = val._gettid()
_active_limbo_lock.release()
return ret
```

where gettid is something like:

```
def _gettid(self):
    if self.__taskid == -1:
        try:
            self.__taskid = ctypes.CDLL('libc.so.6').syscall(186)
        except:
            pass
    return self.__taskid
```

however I am always getting the threadid of the main thread. Are there any changes in the APIs used here between the python versions, causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While porting I missed the _gettid in __bootstrap_inner method. I think it is required  to be called in the context of the thread. In my case earlier it was getting called in the context of the main thread, hence the result.